# How to make a call back function to populate value prop of textinput onChangeText

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

In this code all I'm trying to achieve is that I get the typed value inside the value prop of Textinput. However, what I get is null. A `setState` is asynchronous, I'm lagging one step behind. I am new in react, and I do not know how I can make a callback function that can give me the current value.

I also wish to later use map, and make dynamic form, I appreciate solution that might work for map function as well.

thanks

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Email: null,
      Password: null,
      Address: null,
    };
  }

  EnterValue = (name) => {
    return (text) => {
      this.setState({
        [name]: text,
        
      });
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="enter email"
          value={this.state.Email}
          onChangeText={this.EnterValue('Email')}
          style={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'skyblue', margin: 20 }}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Password"
          value={this.state.Password}
          onChangeText={this.EnterValue('Password')}
          style={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'skyblue', margin: 20 }}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Address"
          value={this.state.Address}
          onChangeText={this.EnterValue('Address')}
          style={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'skyblue', margin: 20 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're saying inside the function you return in the `EnterValue` function, `text` evaluates to `null`?

Comment: Might be helpful for your situation:

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: @weltschmerz thanks for pointing out. fixed. it should pick name argument

Comment: @Dom thanks. still new in react and presently scratching my head how to implement funcions in setState in my situation

Comment: please answer your own question if you get to a solution by yourself

Comment: @salabb I didn't point anything out. I asked a yes/no question.

Comment: @weltschmerz, i edited the question, as your question helped me in addressing error in the script.. The answer is that text represents whatever is written in the text inpurt field

Comment: @salabb I understand that, but that still isn't a yes or no answer to my question...

Comment: @weltschmerz, I fail to understand why you are particular about yes or no. I intend to use this platform, to learn. I already expressed that I an new in react.So i would like to respond  in order for readers to correct my concepts. Respectfully, your yes or not requirement, does not seem to serve the purpose.

Comment: When others ask you questions on this site they want to help. My “requirement” would have helped me help you.

Comment: @weltschmerz that is true.I guess this is also a learning process for me. I would try not to overlook questions next time :)

Comment: Please see my response, for a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124866/how-to-use-setstate-call-back-to-update-value-prop-of-textinput/64125233#64125233

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
onChangeText={(e) => this.EnterValue(e.target.value, 'Email')}
```

( I'm not confident with e.target.value, if it's null or undefined, pass e.target and log it, to see what values you can get from it)

then change your function with the following

```
EnterValue = (value, inputName) => this.setState({ [inputName]: value});
```

Comment: @Axel , thanks for the effort. I tried. it did not work. I guess events are only used for onChange props, and not onChangeText. But it didnt give me error. So i am not sure. Problem persists:)

Comment: Try to do this : 

onChangeText={(e) => this.EnterValue(e, 'Email')};

And console.log the first parameter in your EnterValue function. It might not be an event, I'm not really experienced with react-native. If it's not an event, it can be the value itself, and so your problem will be solved

Comment: @Axel. thanks. please see my response, and thank you for the effort